# How to create a multi y-axis chart with drill down in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, drilldown

http://jsfiddle.net/cgelinas78/pLDeq/54/

A few things...

1. Why aren't the dollar amounts showing up on the left y-axis?
2. When one drills down on the 1st column and then comes back - why does the "Budget" series turn black?

**Here's my code**:

```
 $(function(){ 
    function setChartColumn(name, categories, data, type) { 
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories); 
        var dataLen = data.length; 
        while(chart.series.length>0) 
            chart.series[0].remove(); 
        for(var i = 0; i< dataLen; i++){ 
            chart.addSeries({ 
                type: (i == 0 ? 'column' : 'spline'), 
                name: name[i], 
                data: data[i], 
                color: colors[i] 
            }); 
        } 
    } 
    function setChart(name, categories, data, color, type) { 
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories); 
        var dataLen = data.length; 
        chart.series[0].remove(); 
        if(dataLen === 1){ 
            chart.series[0].remove(); 
        } else { 
            for(var i = 0; i< chart.series.length; i++){ 
                chart.series[i].remove(); 
            } 
        } 
        for(var i = 0; i< dataLen; i++){ 
            chart.addSeries({ 
                type: type, 
                name: name, 
                stacking: 'normal', 
                data: data[i], 
                color: color || 'white' 
            }); 
        } 
    } 
    var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors; 
    var categories = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 
        name = 'Expenses', 
        name2 = 'Budget', 
        data = [
            { 
                y:100,
                drilldown: {
                    name:'Marketing',
                    type:'column',
                    categories:['Silverline','Google','CNN'],
                    data:[
                        {name:'Recommedation',y:15}, 
                        {name: 'Legal Fees', y:50}, 
                        {name: 'Click Ads', y:35}
                    ],

                    color: colors[0]
                }
            },
            { 
                y:402,
                drilldown: {
                    name:'Expenses',
                    type:'column',
                    categories:['1','2','3','4'],
                    data:[
                        {name:'Recommedation',y:67},
                        {name:'Recommedation',y:34},
                        {name:'Recommedation',y:1},
                        {name:'Recommedation',y:11}
                    ],

                    color: colors[0]
                }
            },
            { 
                y:343,
                drilldown: {
                    name:'Misc',
                    type:'column',
                    categories:['A', 'B', 'C'],
                    data:[
                        {name:'Recommendation',y:82},
                        {name:'Area',y:5},
                        {name:'Observation',y:6}
                    ],
                    color: colors[0]
                }
            },
            { 
                y:175,
                drilldown: {
                    name:'A',
                    type:'column',
                    categories:['B','C','D'],
                    data:[
                        {name:'Recommendation',y:17},
                        {name:'Recommendation',y:20},
                        {name:'Recommendation',y:50}
                    ],

                    color: colors[0]
                }
            },
            { 
                y:229,
                drilldown: {
                    name:'Expense 1',
                    type:'column',
                    categories:['Category 1'],
                    data:[
                        {name:'Recommendation',y:15},
                        {name:'Observation',y:2}],
                    color: colors[0]
                }
            },
            { 
                y:533
            }, 
            {y:166}, 
            {y:445}, 
            {y:312}, 
            {y:310}, 
            {y:230}, 
            {y:40}], 
        data2 = [1000,990,851,805,729,699, 650, 550, 450, 350, 250, 150, 50]; 

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({ 
        chart: { 
            renderTo: 'container', 
            zoomType: 'xy' 
        }, 
        title: { 
            text: '2013 Mizuho Budget' 
        }, 
        subtitle: { 
            text: 'Click for more details and click to return.' 
        }, 
        xAxis: [{ 
            categories: categories 
        }], 
        yAxis: [{ 
            labels: { 
                formatter: function(){
                    return '$' + this.value;
                },
                style: { color: '#89A54E' } 
            }, 
            title: { 
                text: 'Budget', 
                style: { color: '#89A54E' } 
            }, 
            opposite: true
        }, 
            { // Secondary yAxis
                gridLineWidth: 0, 
                 labels: {
                     formatter: function() {
                        return '$' + this.value;
                    },
                     style: {color: '#4572A7'}
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Expenses',
                    style: {color: '#4572A7'}
                }
        }], 
        plotOptions: { 
            spline: { showInLegend: true},
            column: { 
                cursor: 'pointer', 
                point: { 
                    events: { 
                        click: 
                        function() { 
                            var drilldown = this.drilldown; 
                            if (drilldown) { 
                                setChart([drilldown.name, drilldown.name1, drilldown.name2, drilldown.name3, drilldown.name4, drilldown.name5],  drilldown.categories,  [drilldown.data, drilldown.data1, drilldown.data2, drilldown.data3, drilldown.data4, drilldown.data5], drilldown.color, [drilldown.type]);  
                            } else { 
                                setChartColumn([name,name2], categories, [data,data2], ['column','column']); 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                }, 
                showInLegend: true, 
                dataLabels: { 
                    enabled: false, 
                    color: colors[0], 
                    style: { fontWeight: 'bold' }, 
                    formatter: function() { 
                        return '$' + this.y; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }, 
        tooltip: { shared: true }, 
        credits:{ enabled:false }, 
        legend: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }, 
        series: [{ 
            name: name, 
            color: '#4572A7', 
            type: 'column', 
            data: data 
        }, 
        { 
            name: name2, 
            color: '#89A54E', 
            type: 'spline', 
            data: data2 
        }] 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You don't have either of your series assigned to use the 2nd axis.  Add yAxis:1 to one of your series and it will show up.

2) You are setting the color of the line originally to #89A54E and then in setChart you set it to color[i]

3) Look at what you are passing into setChart:

```
  setChart([drilldown.name, drilldown.name1, drilldown.name2, drilldown.name3, drilldown.name4, drilldown.name5],  drilldown.categories,  [drilldown.data, drilldown.data1, drilldown.data2, drilldown.data3, drilldown.data4, drilldown.data5], drilldown.color, [drilldown.type]);
```

SetChart adds a series for each of the 3rd parameter: [drilldown.data, drilldown.data1, drilldown.data2, drilldown.data3, drilldown.data4, drilldown.data5]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I updated my code: 

http://jsfiddle.net/pLDeq/50/

The yAxis: 1 didn't work but I found another answer --> linkedTo: 0 --> and that placed in front of the 2nd yaxis worked to link it and display the labels.  

I changed the color of the spline to color[i] in the bottom, but it now appears as black dots - weird.  But when I drill down and come back to the original chart it's a line again.

Comment: How did you put line breaks in your comment?  I tried and it just reverts it back to a big blob of content.

Comment: The black dots are the point markers.  Since you are adding and deleting series, it picks a point marker each time it adds a new series.  You can turn markers off for all your splines:
plotOptions: { 
            spline: { showInLegend: true,
                    marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                        states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }}, ...

Comment: Comments on StackOverflow don't have the same style options as questions and answers (at least not that I've found).